# how to send the data to another page via form tag?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I tried much to fetch my all database data to another PHP page and in the form tag but I unable to do this I easily display all the data in the option tag but I am unable to send it to action tag in form tag here's the code.

```
<?php require "pages/header.php" ?>
<?php
//sesssion_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "apple";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
#include "navbar.php";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_3`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

?>
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sign-in/">

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sign-in/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
<select id="role"  name="role" class="form-signin" class="form-control">
        <?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       #echo $row['model'];
       #echo "<option value="'.$row["model"].'">";

       #echo "<option value='".$row["model"]."' href='".$row["model"]."'>";
      # echo "<a href='".$row["model"]."'>";
       #echo $row['model'];
       #echo "</a>";
      # echo "</option>";?>
      <form action="repaired.php?<?php $row['model'] ?> enctype=multipart/formdata">
      <select id="role"  name="role" class="form-signin" class="form-control">
      <option value='<?php $row['model'] ?>' href='<?php $row['model'] ?>'>
      </option>
      </select> 
      </form>
      <?php

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
#$conn->close();
?>
        </select>
```

Comment: One you are using form inside your select tag which is totally wrong other there is no way to submit your form so you can't post your data to other php page

Comment: So, are you trying to pass the data from the current page to `repaired.php`? Are you getting some sort of error, when you try to do this? Also, see the comment of @MuhammadShareyar - Your markup is all over the place. Your `<link>` should be in your `<head>` part and the `<select>` element BEFORE your `while` loop is very much out of place, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not fully clear to me what your exact problem is. It seems you are trying to pass data from the current page (of which you shared the code) to `repaired.php`.

Since the code you posted is (excuse me for being so blunt) a mess, I'm gonna try to add *some* structure to it (I'm obviously not gonna clean it up very thoroughly, though, that'll be your job).

First, all of your `<link>` tags should be somewhere within your `<head>` part... I would guess on your website, that would be within `header.php`

**pages/header.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your App</title>

    <!-- Place your <link> elements here -->
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sign-in/">

    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sign-in/signin.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Body part begins here
         Place for header elements and navigation here, I guess -->
```

Then, the file where you do all the connection and try to send it via your form, I'm just calling it action.php here. Since I don't know what should be displayed in your `<option>` element, I just took the same as I did for the `value` attribute. Notice, where the `while`-loop is placed, it's INSIDE of your `<select>` element (which itself is INSIDE of your `<form>` element), since you only need ONE of those. You will have multiple `<option>` elements though, so these are the ones inside of your loop. Also, I placed a submit button at the end of the form, which will allow us to submit the form.

**action.php**

```
<?php
include "pages/header.php";

// Database variables and connection
// ...

// Data fetching and displaying
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_3`";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  echo '<form action="repaired.php" method="post">';
  echo '  <select id="role"  name="role" class="form-signin" class="form-control">';

  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '    <option value="' . $row['model'] . '">' . $row['model'] . '</option>';
  }

  echo '  </select>';
  echo '  <button type="submit" name="form_send">Send</button>';
  echo '</form>';
} else {
  echo 'No data found';
}
```

Now, within your `repaired.php` file you obviously need to fetch the posted data. Since I don't know what you want to do with your data, I can just post an idea of what you could do. If you send a form via the `post` method (see code above, `method="post"`) you can access your form data with the `$_POST` superglobal. This is an array that keeps your posted data... The `name` attribute of your form elements will be the key to access your data. So, if I post a form with a single input, and the input has the attribute `name="first_name"`, I can access it's value with `$_POST['first_name']` on the target page (the `action` attribute of your `<form>`). In your case we have a `<select>` with `name="role"`, so you should be able to access it as explained:

**repaired.php**

```
<?php
/* 
   First we check, if the submit button was pressed... If not,
   we echo an error message, if yes, we can proceed to access the posted data
 */
if (!isset($_POST['form_send'])) {
  echo 'No data submitted';
} else {
  echo $_POST['role'];
}
```

My answer, if it even solves your problem, is far from perfect and not tested, so I don't know if there are any errors in it. I suggest you keep on practicing and expanding your knowledge. It's a very good idea to learn how to separate your logic code from your markup. I recommend you reading up on MVC or MOVE or other architectural patterns, or if you want to go an easier route first, read up on template engines (such as [Twig](https://twig.symfony.com/)). Also, I suggest you to expand your knowledge on HTML basics ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) is a good place to do so, IMHO), since it seems to me as if you don't have them quite down yet, judging by how you structured your `<form>` parts.

I still hope, my answer helped you get back on the correct track